# Can a parameterized interface be a subinterface?

Tags: java, list, interface, parameterized

This is a homework assignment that I've been researching for over 2 hours and I still can't get a decent answer, so I would appreciate any help.

Suppose that Bicycle is a subclass of Vehicle.

Is the parameterized interface `List<Bicycle>` a subinterface of `List<Vehicle>` ? Explain briefly.

My issues are:

1. I thought you couldn't even have lists in interfaces, only methods.
2. How can a list be an interface, let alone a subinterface?
3. What is this question even asking, in plain English? :/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should read covariance and contravariance in C# by Eric Lippert: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/16/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-one.aspx

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p might help. Plus, note that `List` is indeed an [interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html).

Comment: But the question is asking whether one is a subinterface of another, not whether they are equal. I read through the links you posted and they explained the latter well (why list bicycle isn't the same as list vehicle), but it doesn't say whether it is a subinterface

Comment: Hold on. The SO question I linked to pointed out why `List<Dog>` isn't a subclass of `List<Animal>`, not just why they aren't the same. The hope was reading that would clear up why `List<Bicycle>` isn't a subinterface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Regarding your issues

1. You are not HAVING a `List` in an interface, `List` itself is an
   interface.
2. `List` of course IS an interface (`LinkedList` and `ArrayList` being the classes implementing it). `List` just provides methods enough to describe a simple list, and `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` provide bodies of those method according to the implementation.
3. To explain the actual question, I'll jot down some facts first. (Sorry if I'm going too basic, but I'm doing it for the sake of completion.)

---

### Regarding the question

- Subinterface means the interface that extends another interface.
- Parametrized interface is the interface which take a class type as a parameter while creating a reference. e.g. `List<Vehicle>` means List is a parametrized interface which has been given `Vehicle` as it's parameter. (Here it means each element of `List` is a `Vehicle`. i.e. it's a list OF vehicles).
- The question is asking whether a parameterized interface `List<Bicycle>` is a subinterface of `List<Vehicle>`. (i.e. if `List<Bicycle>` extends `List<Vehicles>` given the fact that `Bicycle` extends `Vehicle`.

I suppose it should be enough for you to understand the question and partly the answer too..

Good luck.

Comment: You dumbed it down just enough - much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to know it helped.

Comment: I can HAVING `public List<T> getResults()` in my interface as much as I want to ;)

Comment: I was saying about member. But even in this case, you are not having a List in your interface.

Answer (score 0):

*Is the parameterized interface List<Bicycle> a subinterface of List<Vehicle> ? Explain briefly.*

**No.** The List interface is defined for generic types and the defined methods do not change for various type parameters. That is to say, List<x> has the same methods for any x.

*Your issues are:*

1. I thought you couldn't even have lists in interfaces, only methods.
2. How can a list be an interface, let alone a subinterface?
3. What is this question even asking, in plain English? :/

*My answers are:*

1. An interface can have fields (Math.PI), methods, and member classes (SomeParcel.Build). A method can have List as the return type, so a List can be in an interface (e.g [Arrays.asList()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29) ).
2. [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) is *only* an interface. It is a subinterface of Collection and Iterator because List's superinterfaces are Collection and Iterator. In other words, List has all the methods of the superinterface Collection and more, therefore it is a subinterface of Collection.
3. Does List<Bicycle> have more methods than List<Vehicle>?

---

*I may be wrong, so I don't mind if someone wants to teach me about the finer nuances of Java terminology.*